# nginx rewrite rule aways return 403?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

> I want to set production and test ENVs.
>
> And all .cgi files really in /test and /production.
>
> But, when I access https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/p/yyy.cgi it aways return 403.
>
> When I access https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/production/yyy.cgi it works.
>
> what does it happen?
>
> This is my code:

```
  server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/server.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    keepalive_timeout   70;
    server_tokens off;
    fastcgi_param   HTTPS               on;
    fastcgi_param   HTTP_SCHEME         https;
    server_name _;
    root /run/www;
    index  index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html;

    ...

    rewrite ^/p/(.*)$ /production/$1 break;

    ....


    location ~ .*(\.pl|\.cgi)?$
    {
        proxy_set_header  Host             $host;
        set_real_ip_from  180.76.160.246;
        set_real_ip_from  127.0.0.1;
        real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
        real_ip_recursive on;
        gzip on;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001; 
        fastcgi_read_timeout   60;

        expires 1m;  

    }

...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `rewrite...last` instead of `rewrite...break`?

Comment: yes. all useless.

Answer (score 0):

It just because `nginx -s reload` not work.
use `nginx -s quit && nginx` insteed.